# long string stored in VARCHAR mysql outputs as one line

Tags: mysql

I have been searching for the answer to this but cant seem to find it anywhere. My problem is that I have a table with a column name `description` it is set as `VARCHAR(1000)` well I have several very long strings to input into this column but when I use `MySQL` from the command line and want to see all the values `SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE` it will output the contents of the `description` column as one long string and makes the entire screen unreadable unless I stretch the terminal window width wise. Is there a way to prevent this so that it is only as wide as the terminal window so I dont have to stretch the window? Can I add line breaks? I hope I provided enough information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use \G instead of ; at the end of the query. In this way the result will be displayed vertically and will be more readable.

```
SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE\G
```